# WPF TreeViewItem serializer causing memory leaks

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wpf, treeview

In my application I have method which accepts any serializable object and serialize it to populate my TreeView. The xml usually is pretty big and very dynamic, can be 500-1000 lines, but every time I load new XML the RAM is going up, I suspect that my clean up is not correct/full. All methods are listed below

```
public static void PopulateTreeView<T>(this TreeView mainTree, T serializableObject)
        {
            try
            {
                var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDocument.LoadXml(XmlExtensions.SerializeObject(serializableObject));

                var xmlNodes = xmlDocument.DocumentElement;

                var tNode = mainTree.Items[mainTree.Items.Count - 1];

                Task task = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    AddNode(xmlNodes, (TreeViewItem)tNode);
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, @"Exception has occured", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }
```

I can call it very simple with any type of object

```
uxItemsTreeView.PopulateTreeView(_myOrder?.Items);
```

When I load some new xml I am doing a pre-cleanup for that TreeView

```
UserInterfaceHelper.FindVisualChildren<TreeView>(this).ToList().ForEach(x =>
{
           x.Tag = "";
           x.Items.Clear();
});
```

I am failing to see where is the mistake I even tried to remove the child items separately:

```
UserInterfaceHelper.FindVisualChildren<TreeView>(this).ToList().ForEach(x =>
{
          x.Tag = "";
          UserInterfaceHelper.FindVisualChildren<TreeViewItem>(x).ToList().ForEach(y =>
          {
               x.Items.Remove(y);
          });
          x.Items.Clear();
});
```

SerializableObject:

```
public static string SerializeObject(object value)
{
      using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
      {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(value.GetType());
                serializer.Serialize(ms, value);
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
      }
}
```

and Add Note

```
 private static void AddNode(XmlNode inXmlNode, TreeViewItem inTreeNode)
    {
        XmlNode xNode;
        TreeViewItem tNode;
        XmlNodeList nodeList;
        int i;

        if (inXmlNode.HasChildNodes)
        {
            nodeList = inXmlNode.ChildNodes;
            for (i = 0; i <= nodeList.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                xNode = inXmlNode.ChildNodes[i];
                inTreeNode.InvokeEx(x => x.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = xNode.Name }));
                tNode = (TreeViewItem)inTreeNode.Items[i];
                AddNode(xNode, tNode);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            inTreeNode.InvokeEx(x => x.Header = (inXmlNode.OuterXml).Trim());
        }
    }
```

But without any success. Depending on the object RAM can easily go more than 100MB+ on each load. 
Can someone help me how can I dispose the old one properly ?

Comment: What is `XmlExtensions.SerializeObject` and `AddNode`?

Comment: I have updated my question, you can find them there.

Comment: *"All methods are listed below"* - [sigh](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The fact that the memory hasn't been returned to the OS doesn't indicate that the garbage collector is losing track of objects in that memory.

Comment: okay, then what would you suggest to resolve it, because the application 20-30 min of usage, RAM can grow to 500MB. I am trying different things, but really stuck, nothing helps...